# Safe alternative to calling of abstract method from constructor

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I know it's a bad idea, and it causes bugs. The problem is, I need the "intended" behavior.

"Low":

```
// simplified example
abstract class Low {        
    String name;

    public Low(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }       

    public Low(int id) {
        this.name = getNameForId(id);
    }  

    public Low() {} // will be loaded later

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }   

    public void load(InputStream in) {
        // --- grab ID from stream ---
        this.name = getNameForId(id);
    }

    protected abstract String getNameForId(int id);
}
```

And "High":

```
class High extends Low {        
    public High(int id) { super(id); }      
    public High(String name) { super(name); } 
    public High() {} // will be loaded later

    @Override
    protected String getNameForId(int id)
    {
        return Registry.getName(id);
    }
}
```

Note that in this particular case, it will work just fine. But it will fall apart once the overriding method needs to use some field.

How to do this better?

Comment: Can you give an example of the case where things fall apart?  I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: if class High returns this.myNameField in getName(), it will not have yet been initialized and will return null.

Comment: Yes, but then the `Low` constructor would be saying `this.name = getName()`, and `getName()` would return `this.name`, so that would be nonsensical in the first place.  You'd be setting a variable equal to itself.

Comment: okay I will work on a better example.

Comment: If you're defining an abstract method to get the name, why do you need a member variable to hold it? Just have `toString()` (and anything else that needs it) call `getName()`

Comment: Now I've modified the example to be more accurate.

Comment: And again. Please look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to separate out loading a name for an ID from your Low and High objects. Introduce an interface for loading names given an ID.

```
public interface NameProvider
{
  String getNameForId(String id);
}
```

Add specific implementations for each source of names.

```
public class InputStreamNameProvider implements NameProvider
{
  private InputStream inputStream;

  // Constructor 

  public String getNameForId(String id)
  {
     // return name loaded via inputStream
  }
}

public class RegistryNameProvider implements NameProvider
{
  public String getNameForId(String id)
  {
     return Registry.getName(id);
  }
}
```

You could then add a new constructor to Low that takes the NameProvider and String id as arguments

```
public Low(NameProvider provider, String id)
{
  this(provider.getNameForId(id));
}
```

or even use the name provider before constructing the instance of Low or High. The main idea is the separation of loading the name for an ID from the Low and High objects.

Comment: An abstract method with the @PostConstruct annotation would have worked as well, because that will ensure the constructors of both super as current class have finished initialising all attributes before the method is called implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid calling the abstract method by adding a `public void load(int id)` method (like you do for InputStream) and removing the `Constructor(int id)`.

You might want to add some Factory functionality to ensure your constructed instance is can never be accessed without having a proper name value.